# How can I add a hotkey to the pose asset shelf

Tags: shortcut, pose-mode

How can I add a new shortcut to *Apply Pose Flipped* in the Pose Asset Shelf?

[image: Apply Pose Flipped]

Comment: for me - this is a bug

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks.